# Angular 5 reactive forms Primary key

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

How do you deal with object unique ID / primary key?
Do you add it to the FormGroup?

```
 this.user = this.fb.group({
  id: [''],
  name: ['', Validators.required ]
});
```

Comment: deal with object _unique ID / primary key_ what do you mean by this ?

Comment: @RahulSingh Imagine that I am editing an object, I set the formGroup With his value. When I want to save to form I dont have the unique ID on the form...

Comment: you can have this value as an input field with a hidden attribute so that you can use it to edit or save it this might help you in your case

Comment: @RahulSingh I did it that way. But I was wondering if I have a more polite way to do it.

Comment: i added an answer might help your cause

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two possible ways i can think of .

**One**

> Have this value as an input field with a hidden attribute so that you
>   can use it to edit or save during submit

**Second**

> The other way is as you are making use of Reactive Forms you need not
>   have it as an hidden field as you know with reactive Forms you have
>   data as part of `NgForm` when anything changes . What you can do is
>   create a dummy Submit button for the same and at the time of submit
>   have all the data of form and append the data from the api for the id
>   and then pass it to the service . Only down side is you cannot use
>   native form submit

Comment: If I choose the first option is there any way to disable the attribute ?

Comment: disable the attribute means ? you can right you are dealing with input disabled should wrk

Comment: I googled and I think that's possible to do something like this.      
    'first': new FormControl({value: 'hello', disabled: false})